# Array is still empty after GET request

Tags: html, angular, typescript, get, fetch

I have an < ul> and each < li> contains the name, age, market value etc. of a player. These attributes are coming from a database. The players are shown in the browser properly, but in typescript I'm trying to add these player < li>-s to the "playerElements" array. I'm pretty sure I'm doing this after the fetch ended, but the array is still empty and I have no idea why.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Roster column -->
    <ul class="col-5 roster">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-3">
          <h2>Roster</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Players in roster column -->
      <li *ngFor="let player of myPlayers" class="row player" id="{{player.playerid}}" draggable="true">
        <div class="col">
          <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            [attr.data-bs-target]="'#player'+ player.playerid"
            aria-expanded="false"
            [attr.data-bs-target]="'#player'+ player.playerid"
            [attr.aria-controls]="player.playerid"
          >
            {{player.name}}
          </button>

          <div class="collapse" id="player{{player.playerid}}">
            <div class="card card-body">
              <!-- Age -->
              <div class="row my-2">
                <div class="col-4">Age</div>
                <div class="col">{{player.age}}</div>
              </div>
              <!-- Wage -->
              <div class="row my-2">
                <div class="col-4">Wage</div>
                <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
                  {{player.wage}} <i class="bi bi-coin ml-2 ms-1"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Market Value -->
              <div class="row my-2">
                <div class="col-4">Market Value</div>
                <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
                  {{player.marketvalue}} <i class="bi bi-coin ml-2 ms-1"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
             
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyPlayer } from './MyPlayer';
import { delay } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myteam',
  templateUrl: './myteam.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myteam.component.scss'],
})
export class MyteamComponent {
  title = 'topfive';

  playerElements: any[] = [];
  myPlayers: Array<MyPlayer> = [];

  constructor() {
    this.fetchData().then(() => {
      this.initializePlayerElements();
    });
  }

  async fetchData() {
    const url = 'https://localhost:7176/Player';
    let objects = (await (await fetch(url)).json()).filter(
      (player: any) => player.teamid === 1
    );

    objects.map((object: any) => {
      let myplayer = new MyPlayer();
      Object.assign(myplayer, object);
      this.myPlayers.push(myplayer);
    });
    console.log(this.myPlayers);
  }


  initializePlayerElements() {
    this.playerElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.player'));
    console.log(this.playerElements)
  }
}
```